# How to import Tivoli Workload Scheduler processes into the Bluemix Workload Scheduler?

Tags: import, ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

In the Bluemix Workload Scheduler service, there is mention of a way to import processes.  Does this mean that it's possible to import processes from the on-prem Tivoli Workload Scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's also possible to import on-prem Tivoli Workload Scheduler definitions.

Depending on your need you can also consider using IBM Workload Application on Cloud from IBM Marketplace, instead of using the Bluemix service.

The primary interface on Workload Scheduler service on Bluemix is currently the Application Lab, not the Dynamic Workload Console.

If the definitions has been created on the Application Lab also on-prem, they can be exported from the Application Lab on-prem, and imported in the Application Lab on Bluemix.

If the definitions has been created with Dynamic Workload Console or by composer, they can be imported using Workload Application Templates or using composer.

Workload Application Templates is the best choice if your on-prem version is 9.1 or later. Create a Workload Application Template in the on-prem, export it and the import that on Workload Scheduler on Bluemix. Currently to access the workload application import on Bluemix, Launch the Application Lab, right-click on a process and select Advanced Options -> Monitor from DWC, in the DWC menu select Administration -> Import Workload Application.

An alternative is to extract the definitions from on-prem with composer and import them with composer into Workload Scheduler for Bluemix. To access composer, download and install an agent locally on-prem, this comes with composer. You can use the API hostname, userid and password as credentials for composer.